How to set repository for gradle dependencies
I need to specify a repository for gradle dependencies.

I have an Android project with groovy for gradle.
All the dependencies are downloaded form Nexus repository (This is the organization requirementes).
I've added convention plugin recently.
After that I have 26 dependencies loaded from repo.gradle.org. These are different groovy dependencies.
There is such a dependencies in the Nexus repository, but it is not requested.
I've tried to add this repository to pluginManagement.repository in main settings.gradle and in build-logic's. I've tried to set pluginManagement at first place in scripts. But no luck. Each time I'm starting to sync it ignores nexus repositiory and uses repo.gradle.org.
Where this repository is set and how to change it?

UPD
It looks like only Android Studio itself downloads this dependencies.

UPD
It seems the only way for now to acheave this is to use GRADLE_LIBS_REPO_OVERRIDE environment variable.
There is a feature request to move it to properties and a PR that was closed without merging as there are some other plans for now.

UPD
Right. It seems the only way for now to acheave this is to use GRADLE_LIBS_REPO_OVERRIDE environment variable.
There is a feature request to move it to properties and a PR that was closed without merging as there are some other plans for gradle libs repo setting.

Maybe this can help:
navigate to your .m2 Folder (on windows C:\Users\<yourname>\.m2)
There should be a settings.xml there you can fill in the URL of your Repository.
The XML should look like this:
    <servers>
 
    </servers>
  <mirrors>

    <mirror>

        <id>Nexus</id>

        <name>put the name of the nexus here</name>

        <url>put the url of the Repository here</url>

        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>

    </mirror>

  </mirrors>

</settings>


Thanks for your andswer. But I have no settings.xml in my .m2 folder. I've tried to create it but no luck.
Anyways, I need this setting to be done in project files as other developers should have this working without need to change locak files.
